# Input binding to custom class doesn't seem to work for blob

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions

My Azure Function has two input parameters:

- Event Hubs trigger
- Blob input binding

I am trying to bind both parameters to custom type (F# record in my case). Binding works fine for the trigger, but not for blog binding, which gives the following error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.MailboxFanOut'. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Blob to type 'Run+CustomerName'.
```

Here is the code:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type CustomerName = {
    UserName: string
}

let Run(item: CustomerName, userNames: CustomerName, log: TraceWriter) =
    log.Verbose("F# function executing")
```

Replacing F# record with a class doesn't help...

Here is the function definition:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "item",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "blabla",
      "connection": "eventhubs",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "userNames",
      "path": "tada/123",
      "connection": "foo",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blob bindings unfortunately don't currently support POCO bindings as you'd expect. We have an open issue in our repo tracking this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/995).

To work around that, I recommend binding to a Stream, string, or one of the other supported types and doing the deserialization into your POCO type in your method.

Comment: Ah, thanks, good to know. The docs are saying they are supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob P.S. the "SO question" link in the github issue is broken, it's pointing to itself

Comment: Yeah, I had also logged a doc bug for that :) https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/180. We'll get it fixed :)

Comment: Better fix the SDK ;)